Error connecting to WiFi using connman on a IMX8mp board
I have an IMX8MP board running a Yocto Poky build image. It's running a small HTTP server in order for a user to input an SSID_NAME and a PASSPHRASE. Once the server receives those, I want to connect to the Wi-Fi that the user inputs. I tried creating the file in /var/lib/connman/wifi_XXXXX_YYYYY_managed_psk/settings. The content of the file is:
[wifi_XXXXX_YYYYY_managed_psk]
SSID=YYYYY
Name=SSID_NAME
Passphrase=PASSPHRASE
AutoConnect=true

However, I get an error when I try to connect by doing connmanctl connect wifi_XXXXX_YYYYY_managed_psk:
Error /net/connman/service/wifi_XXXXX_YYYYY_managed_psk: Not registered

The reason why I'm creating the file and then executing the connect command, is  because the connmanctl connect wifi_XXXXX_YYYYY_managed_psk asks for a Passphrase, and I don't know how to pass it with a script.
Additional information
This is the script I'm using to connect
#!/bin/sh

NAME=$1
PASSWORD=$2
mac=$(ifconfig wlan0 | grep ether | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/://g')

connmanctl scan wifi

# Match the wifi network with the given NAME and mac address
ssid=$(connmanctl services | grep -E "^\s*$NAME\s+wifi_$mac" | grep -o 'wifi_[0-9a-fA-F]*_[0-9a-fA-F]*_managed_psk')

path=/var/lib/connman/$ssid

echo "Setting up configuration for wifi network $NAME, $mac, $ssid"

mkdir -p $path
configuration_file=$path/settings
touch $configuration_file

cat >$configuration_file <<_EOF
[$ssid]
SSID=$ssid
Name=$NAME
Passphrase=$PASSWORD
AutoConnect=true
_EOF

connmanctl config $ssid
connmanctl connect $ssid

exit 0


I also tried @Insight Seeker's suggestion of using connmanctl config wifi_XXXXX_YYYYY_managed_psk --passphrase PASSPHRASE instead of creating the file. Got the exact same error.

The error you're encountering with ConnMan (Not registered) typically indicates that the service you are trying to connect to has not been discovered or initialized properly by ConnMan.
Here, your situation is described.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly I still have the same issue. I don't see any errors on journalctl or anywhere other than the Not registered

I think you forgot to specify agent on after scan wifi, try:
connmanctl agent on
After connmanctl scan wifi
